# How are the job approval ratings of Governor Andrew Cuomo and mayor Bill de Blasio faring during the COVID-19 crisis?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, public-opinion

There has been [a question here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/52285/how-has-the-handling-of-the-coronavirus-outbreak-covid-19-affected-donald-trum) about the job approval rating of Trump in this Covid-19 pandemic. (Slight increase.)

I wonder how the governor and mayor of US [most affected US state & city](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/powerpost/paloma/daily-202/2020/03/27/daily-202-new-york-city-is-ground-zero-again-with-the-coronavirus-pandemic/5e7d9a0d88e0fa101a753f58/), that is NYC (and NY state) are doing in the opinion polls lately.

Comment: Why is this a bad question, but one about Trump's approval rating is ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of them, but particularly Cuomo, have received exceptionally high marks.

According to a Siena poll posted on March 30th with data collected 3/22 - 3/26, approval of Cuomo’s pandemic response is 87-11, including 70% approval from Republicans! DeBlasio’s is lower, but still quite good at 61-31 approval to disapproval.

[image]

The above figures are specifically about how well they've done to address the pandemic, but Cuomo’s overall approval has also improved by 54 points to a near record high of 71-23.

[image]

https://scri.siena.edu/2020/03/30/87-of-nyers-approve-of-cuomos-handling-of-the-coronavirus/

---

The Hill is also reporting on a national poll conducted by Harvard CAPS/Harris from March 24th - March 26th which shows Cuomo with a *national* approval rating of 45%, nearly as high as Trump with 48%. Annoyingly, I can't find that actual data anywhere, so we just have to go off the quotes they provide:

> Forty-five percent of Americans say they have a favorable view of how New York Gov. Andrew Cuomo (D) is responding to the coronavirus pandemic, according to a new Harvard CAPS/Harris poll released exclusively to The Hill.
>
> Harvard CAPS/Harris polling director Mark Penn told The Hill. "No question he is seen now as a leader at least with Democrats and not seen as partisan since he is favorable right now by 2 to 1."
>
> [Cuomo favorability in US hits 45 percent: poll](https://thehill.com/homenews/state-watch/490177-cuomo-favorability-in-US-hits-45-percent-poll)

If we take Penn at is word, that would mean that his approval is 45%, disapproval is ~ 22% and no opinion is 33%. While 45% doesn't sound that high, I'd argue that it's surprising for that many people nationwide to have a positive opinion of a local politician from another state.

Comment: Interesting, the Cuomo [graph](https://scri.siena.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/chart3_320-1024x671.png) is really worth adding. Also the NYT [headline](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/04/01/business/media/deblasio-coronavirus-response.html) "Cuomo Is a Media Hero in the Pandemic. De Blasio Is a Scapegoat."